# restkit installation into xcode - is it always this complex?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, json

Trying to use the restkit framework into my xcode project, and they have an "installation guide" at their github page (https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit, scroll down to xcode 4.2)

OK, so being a 2-weeks objective-c coming in from the Java world, please excuse me:

This guide is 10 steps, half of it i don't even understand what it is... Is it just me, or is this extremely complex, just to be able to use a third-party api?

If something goes wrong, i'll stand as much chance as a snowman in hell to understand whats going on let alone fixing it...

Comment: Nobody promised you that life is easy.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried the visual guide? [Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions under "Xcode 4.x (Git Submodule)"

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

Seems to be the simpler of the two to follow from a new user perspective. Although I'm not sure what's not to get in the top one? Perhaps explain where it is you're having trouble. i.e. which step of the 10/12 steps do you need assistance with?

Comment: Thanks, i have done that on their googlegroups page. There are a couple of steps(11-14) i couldn't match up with my 4.2 view of xcode, hopefully someone there can help...

Answer (score 0):

in their documentation recommended to use **cocoapods** for installation: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-via-CocoaPods